# Blazor .NET Core app not deploying on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a blazor app on IIS following the article below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

I've installed IIS version 10.0 using the following settings:

[image]

I then created the site and changed the application pool to No Managed Code

[image]

I created a new Blazor app and deployed it immediately without changing a thing (so I know there's not a problem with the code). Looking in the project properties it's using .NET Core 3.1

I noticed there was no web.config file when I built the Release version.

I copied the Release version to the website directory.

Browsing to the site gives me a 403.14 - Forbidden error.

[image]

I read in another article to try configuring the Mapping Handlers this was the current state of the handlers:

[image]

I added a module mapping like so:

[image]

I now get a 500 error:

[image]

The web.config file currently looks like this:

[image]

I then read to add this aspCore line to the configuration file:

[image]

After that it looks like it loads but with none of the formatting.

[image]

I assumed hosting a Blazor site on IIS would be a simple thing to do, would someone be able to point me to where I am going wrong?

Comment: You can try this link to [publish blazor to iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116982/how-do-i-publish-a-blazor-asp-net-app-in-iis)

Comment: You may read this tutorial https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-blazor-application-to-iis/

Comment: This link will tell you about how to deploy an ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor application of IIS 10 and it still has roubleshoot some of the common hosting issues for a Blazor application: [Deploying A Blazor Application On IIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis).