# Blazor Server App routing 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created a blazor server app. it is working on my machine when it is running using localhost. There is a folder configured in the IIS for this project.

I have published the project to a folder and then copied/paste the dll files to the configured folder in the IIS.

The main page (index page) is running perfect , but when I tried to click to move to another page, I got the error "404 - File or directory not found".

Note :- when I browse the project from the IIS , the name of the project has been replaced from localhost to abcdef.com.

Could anyone help me to correct the routing problem ?

Comment: There are many, many tutorials out on the Internet about how to deploy a Blazor project.    Have you followed any of these?  The information you have provided so far doesn't help much in solving your problem.

Comment: Yes , I did that , but I believe there something wrong in routing.

Comment: It almost certainly isn't loading because either the Blazor JS code isn't loading and/or the Blazor Hub Session isn't running.  Check the Browser for JS errors and post them in your question.

Comment: I found the problem , but I don't know how to solve it. When we add the blazor application inside the "Default Web Site" , it will not work , but if we add new website , it will work (no routing problems). I want to keep it in the Default Web Site.

Comment: Hi @Developer ,Why don't you publish the project directly to IIS ? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116982/how-do-i-publish-a-blazor-asp-net-app-in-iis)

Comment: Yes , I did that and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its related to your page definition of your Balzor components. "/" means the root folder of your website. If you want to add this application to your existing website, you probably upload it in a new folder in your host. For example https yourwebsite/app. In this scenario your new application is not root of your website anymore. So your page address should be something like this:
`@page "/app/address"`.

Comment: This is correct because when I published my application to a separate website , it works. Thank you