# Blazor Service-Worker.js geting blocked on Blazor Server / Client App running on IIS 10

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, webassembly, iis-10

- Blazor Server+Client app in one project
- .Net 6.0
- Works great locally although not in IIS Express, only Chrome/Other browser
- Published Server build to IIS
- Finds other files in same folder but fails to load Service-Worker.js
- Microsofts own demo project for MS Auth Weather Forecast also fails with the error
  "There was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')'"

  - I did find some stuff on SO about the above error but none of those solutions work/can be applied to my style of program.cs (its the one with Index.html and no main).

The error message seems to indicate that it can't find the file Service-Worker.js (or "see" it) but it can see others such as bootstrap in the same folder and in fact loaded them:

[image: Edge network tab shows success on some files]

```
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
localhost/:1  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') with script ('https://localhost/service-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
localhost/:1  Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
blazor.webassembly.js:1 info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SupportSSPHelper.ServerAPI.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://localhost:7171/api/WebProducts/GetCategories
blazor.webassembly.js:1 info:
```

**Things I have tried:**

- uninstall/reinstall of IIS 10
- delete of all bin/obj folders and flushing cache
- attempted to get Kestrel to work but couldn't - think its already using it
- gave 'everyone' temporary access to folder just in case
- made sure that ".net 7 hosting bundle" is installed (believe backward compatible with 6)
- followed the Microsoft guide for publishing to IIS
- Tried using the demo (with MS Auth security as i need that) it also fails

Finally Followed this guide from scratch - no joy: [How do i publish a Blazor ASP.NET App in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116982/how-do-i-publish-a-blazor-asp-net-app-in-iis)

Comment: You need to make sure your service-worker.js file is in the same directory as the .html file corresponding to the page you're on.

Comment: Done that, they all are unfortunately. thanks though.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.